# On the sum of uniform independent random variables

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be independent uniform random variables in [0,1] and assume $c>1/2$. Is it true that $$\mathbb{P}\left[\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \leq n \cdot c\right]$$ is increasing with respect to $n$?

I know that the sum of uniform independent random follows Irwin–Hall distribution, but it seems hard to work with the pdf. Maybe a coupling argument? I want to stress that we want to show the result for all $n$, not only for $n$ sufficiently large.

Comment: Based om simulation, I think the result is true, presuming "increasing" is interpreted as meaning  "non-decreasing" (in order to cover $c \ge 1$). I leave the proof to you.

Comment: I did simulations too. That is why I asked the question. The proof is all that matters...

Comment: I have a feeling this might be rather subtle, at least for $c$ close to $1/2$. I just posted and deleted an incorrect answer, and the summary of that is that there are competing effects.

Comment: I saw the post, where was the mistake?

Comment: The fact that $p_n''<0$ actually works against me, and I need the asymmetry of the interval I'm averaging over to at least compensate for this.

Comment: Maybe it's possible to prove this by putting error bounds on the approximation of the distribution as a normal distribution. Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31365/connection-to-normal-distribution http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30468/error-in-normal-approximation-to-a-uniform-sum-distribution

Comment: @BenCrowell: We're not in the regime of the CLT though, our probabilities are close to $1$ (we're many standard deviations away from the mean).

Comment: @BenCrowell --- the large-$n$ limit is actually reached very early, I didn't do a formal error bound analysis, but the numerics indicates a rapid convergence, see the plot at the end of my posting.

Comment: You want Bates distribution ... not Irwin-Hall.

Comment: And the result should follow conceptually ... the $\text{Bates}(n)$ distribution has a constant mean at $\frac12$, and as $n$ increases, the pdf becomes more peaked ... it has variance of $\frac{1}{12n}$, so as $n$ increases, the distribution narrows and converges upon the mean , i.e. if $Z \sim \text{Bates}(n)$, then $P(Z < c)$, for $c > 1/2$ (the mean) must be increasing in $n$.

Comment: [ and mode at 1/2 ]

Comment: @wolfies: The Bates and IH distributions are related by $B_n(x)=IH_n(nx)$, so either one is fine. In any event, I'd love to see a proof of the claims you're making (why does the density "become more peaked"), so if you have one, please post.

Comment: @ChristianRemling --- correct me if I have misunderstood you, but isn't this "peaked density" just the derivative with respect to $\delta$ of the sinc integral in my posting below, so this distribution tends for $n\rightarrow\infty$ to  $P_n(\delta)\rightarrow\sqrt{6n/\pi}\exp(-6n\delta^2)$ (with $\delta=c-1/2$)

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: Yes, the density is $P'_n$ in your notation and $p'_n$ in mine, and $P_n\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$ for fixed $c$, but that's clear and doesn't address the original question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is yes. Let $S_n:=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, $x\in\mathbb R$, $n=2,3,\dots$, and 
\begin{equation}
 G_n(x):=P(S_n/n\le x)=\frac1{n!}\,\sum_j(-1)^j\binom nj (nx-j)_+^n,  
\end{equation}
where $u_+:=0\vee u$; cf. **[[Irwin--Hall distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution)]**. 
The summation here is over all integers $j$, with the usual convention that $\binom nj=0$ if $j\notin\{0,\dots,n\}$. 
Let 
\begin{equation}
 D_n(x):=G_{n+1}(x)-G_n(x). 
\end{equation}
We have to show that $D_n(x)\ge0$ for $x\ge1/2$.

Clearly, $D_n$ is $n-1$ times continuously differentiable, $D_n=0$ outside $(0,1)$, and $D_n(1-x)=-D_n(x)$ (symmetry). 
For small $x>0$, one has $G_n(x)=\frac1{n!}\,n^nx^n>\frac1{(n+1)!}\,(n+1)^{n+1}x^{n+1}=G_{n+1}(x)$, whence $D_n(x)<0$, whence $D_n>0$ in a left neighborhood of $1$, with $D_n(1)=0$. Also, $D_n(1/2)=0$. 
So, it suffices to show that $D_n$ has no roots in $(1/2,1)$.

Suppose the contrary. Then, by the symmetry, $D_n$ has at least $3$ roots in $(0,1)$. Then, by the Rolle theorem, the derivative $G_n^{(n-1)}$ of $G_n$ of order $n-1$ has at least $3+n-1=n+2$ roots in $(0,1)$. 
This contradicts the fact (proved below) that, for each integer $j$ such that $n-1\ge j\ge\frac{n-1}2$, $D_n$ has exactly one root in interval 
$$h_{n,j}:=[\tfrac jn,\tfrac{j+1}n).$$

Indeed, take any $x\in[1/2,1]$. It is not hard to see that, for $j_x:=j_{n,x}:=\lfloor nx\rfloor$, 
\begin{equation}
 G_n^{(n-1)}(x)=n^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{j_x}(-1)^j\binom nj (nx-j) 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 =\frac{n^{n-1}}{n-1}(-1)^{j_x}\binom n{j_x+1}({j_x}+1) ((n-1)x-{j_x}).  
\end{equation}
Similarly, for $k_x:=j_{n+1,x}$, 
\begin{equation}
 G_{n+1}^{(n-1)}(x)=\frac{(n+1)^{n-1}}{2n(n-1)}
(-1)^{k_x}\binom{n+1}{k_x+1}(k_x+1)P(n,k_x,x),   
\end{equation}
where 
\begin{equation}
 P(n,k,x):=-2 k \left(n^2-1\right) x+k (k n-1)+n \left(n^2-1\right) x^2. 
\end{equation}
Note that $k_x\in\{j_x,j_x+1\}$. 
Now we have to consider the following two cases.

Case 1: $k_x=j_x=j\in[\frac{n-1}2,n-1]$, which is equivalent to $x\in h'_{n,j}:=[\frac jn,\frac{j+1}{n+1})$. It also follows that in this case $j\ge n/2$. In this case, it is not hard to check that $D_n(x)$ equals $(-1)^j P_{n,j,1}(x)$ in sign, where 
\begin{equation}
 P_{n,j,1}(x):=2 j n^n (n-j)+x \left(-2 (n-1) n^n (n-j)-2 j (n+1)^n \left(n^2-1\right)\right)+j (n+1)^n (j n-1)+(n+1)^n
   \left(n^2-1\right) n x^2, 
\end{equation}
which is convex in $x$. Moreover, $P_{n,j,1}(\frac jn)$ and $P_{n,j,1}(\frac{j+1}{n+1})$ each equals $2 n^n - (1 + n)^n<0$ in sign. So, $P_{n,j,1}<0$ and hence $D_n$ has no roots in $h''_{n,j}=[\frac jn,\frac{j+1}{n+1})$.

Case 2: $k_x=j+1$ and $j_x=j\in[\frac{n-1}2,n-1]$, which is equivalent to $x\in h''_{n,j}:=[\frac{j+1}{n+1},\frac{j+1}n)$. In this case, it is not hard to check that $D_n(x)$ equals $(-1)^{j+1} P_{n,j,2}(x)$ in sign, where 
\begin{equation}
 P_{n,j,2}(x):=(j+1) \left((n+1)^n (j n+n-1)-2 j n^n\right)+2 (j+1) \left((n-1) n^n-(n+1)^n \left(n^2-1\right)\right) x+n
   \left(n^2-1\right) (n+1)^n x^2, 
\end{equation}
which is convex in $x$. Moreover, $P_{n,j,1}(\frac{j+1}n)$ and $-P_{n,j,1}(\frac{j+1}{n+1})$ each equals $2 n^n - (1 + n)^n<0$ in sign. So, $P_{n,j,2}$ has exactly one root in $h''_{n,j}$ and hence so does $D_n$.

Since the interval $h_{n,j}$ is the disjoint union of $h'_{n,j}$ and $h''_{n,j}$, $D_n$ has exactly one root in $h_{n,j}=[\tfrac jn,\tfrac{j+1}n)$, and the proof is complete.

Comment: Hi Iosif,can you explain this: "Then, by the Rolle theorem, the derivative $G^{(n−1)}_n$  of $G_n$ of order $n−1$ has at least $n+2$ roots"

Comment: There are two typos here -- sorry. Of course, I meant to say "the derivative $D_n^{(n-1)}$ of $D_n$ of order $n-1$ has at least $3+n-1=n+2$ roots in $(0,1)$".

Comment: Here are details on the previous comment.  
On supposing that your conjecture is false, we saw that $D_n$ must have at least $3$ roots in $(0,1)$. Plus, $0$ and $1$ are roots of $D_n$ (and of its derivatives of orders up to $n-1$). So, $D_n$ must have at least $5$ roots in $[0,1]$. By Rolle's theorem, strictly between any two roots of a differentiable function there is at least one root of its derivative.

Comment: [Continuation of the previous comment:] So, $D'_n$ must have at least $5-1=4=3+1$ roots in $(0,1)$. Continuing thus and using the fact that $D_n$ is $n-1$ times continuously differentiable, we see that $D_n^{(n-1)}$ must have at least $3+n-1=n+2$ roots in $(0,1)$. Please let me know if you have more questions about this answer.

Answer (score 3):

Let's write $p_n(x)=P(S_n\le nx)$; we want to show that this increases in $n$ for fixed $x>1/2$. By conditioning on $X_{n+1}$, we obtain that
$$
p_{n+1}(x) = \int_0^1 p_n\left( x+ \frac{x-y}{n} \right) \, dy = n\int_{x-(1-x)/n}^{x+x/n} p_n(t)\, dt .
$$
So we're asking if
$$
p_n(x) \le n \int_{x-(1-x)/n}^{x+x/n} p_n(t)\, dt  \quad\quad\quad\quad (1)
$$
By a Taylor expansion, the RHS of (1) equals
$$
p_n(x) + p_n'(x) \frac{2x-1}{2n} + O(p_n''/n^2) ,
$$
so we'd be done if we could establish that $|p_n''(t)|\lesssim n p_n'(x)$ near $t=x$ with a sufficiently small implied constant. If we go back to the Irwin Hall distribution $F_n(a)=P(S_n\le a)$, then this becomes $|F_n''(t)|\lesssim F_n'(nx)$ near $t=nx$, and at least for large $n$, this is true since $F''_n$ doesn't vary much on an interval of length $L$, so it can't be much larger than $F'_n(x)/L$.

**Comment:** If we go back to (1), we see that there are competing effects. On the one hand, we're averaging over an asymmetric interval, giving preference to points $t>x$ where $p_n(t)>p_n(x)$, which is good. On the other hand, $p_n''<0$, which is bad, because this means that $p_n$ decreases more rapidly going to the left of $x$ than it increases going to the right.

Comment: Why don't you go with first order approximation?

Comment: Also, can you explain how did you use taylor for (1)?

Comment: This can't work because it doesn't address the key issue mentioned in my final paragraph. On a more technical level, we'd be dealing with $n\int p_n'(\xi_t)(t-x)\, dt$, and I can't tell what the sign of this is.

Comment: We use mean value theorem for the first order, RHS becomes $p_n(x)+p_{n}'(\xi) \frac{2x-1}{n}$ for some $\xi \in (x-x/n,x+x/n)$. We know that $p_n'(\xi)>0$.

Comment: @user31317: I don't know how you want to argue, but you're missing something because I can easily cook up function with positive derivative for which the RHS is $<p_n(x)$ (see my comment again).

Comment: Yes but we know that $p_i(1/2)=1/2$ for all $i$

Comment: I see what you are saying.

Comment: Do you think we can do a coupling between $n$ and $n+1$ sums?

Answer (score 3):

Let me write $c=1/2+\delta$ and define 
$$P_n(\delta)\equiv \mathbb{P}\left[\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \leq n \cdot c\right].$$
Note that $P_n(0)=1/2$ and $P_n(1/2)=1$, irrespective of $n$.

It is convenient to work with the characteristic function of the [Irwin-Hall distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution). I find the principal value integral 
$$\mathbb{P}\left[\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \leq n \cdot c\right]=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty dt\,\frac{1}{(it)^{n+1}}\left(e^{it(1-c)}-e^{-ict}\right)^n,$$
which can be rewritten as
$$P_n(\delta)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^\infty dt\,\sin(2nt\delta)\,\frac{\sin^n t}{t^{n+1}}.$$

[image]

The plot shows $P_n(\delta)$ for $n=1,2,3,4$, from bottom curve to top curve.
We need to demonstrate that this ordering of $P_n(\delta)$ with increasing $n$ holds for all $n$, so $P_n(\delta)$ increases with $n$ for all $\delta\in(0,1/2)$. I will attempt to prove this in several steps.

**(I) $P_n(\delta)$ increases with $n$ near $\delta=0$.**

For small $\delta$ the integral evaluates to

$$P_n(\delta)=\tfrac{1}{2}+2nC_n\delta+{\cal O}(\delta^3),$$

with the coefficient

$$C_n=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\infty dt\,\frac{\sin^n t}{t^n}.$$

This integral over the $n$-th power of the sinc function is [well-studied](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SincFunction.html), we need to show that it decreases more slowly than $1/n$. For small $n$ this can be checked by explicit calculation, for large $n$ it follows from the asymptotic decay $C_n\propto 1/\sqrt n$. So the slope $P'_n(0)=2nC_n\propto \sqrt n$ is indeed an increasing function of $n$.

**(II) $P_n(\delta)$ increases with $n$ near $\delta=1/2$.**

This follows from a similar expansion around $\delta=1/2$, which shows that the first nonzero $p$-th order derivative $P_n^{(p)}(1/2)$ occurs for $p=n$. So near $\delta=1/2$ the function expands as

$$P_n(\delta)=1-(-1)^n A_n(\delta-1/2)^n+{\cal O}(\delta-1/2)^{n+1},\;\;A_n>0,$$

hence $P_n(\delta)$ increases with $n$ for $\delta$ just below $1/2$.

**(III) Large-$n$ asymptotics**

For $n\gg 1$ the sinc integral can be evaluated in closed form by means of the limit
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{\sin(t/\sqrt n)}{t/\sqrt n}\right)^n=\exp(-t^2/6)$$
so that $P_n(\delta)$ becomes asymptotically
$$P_n(\delta)\rightarrow\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\infty dt\,\sin(2t\delta\sqrt n)\frac{1}{t}\exp(-t^2/6)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\,{\rm Erf}\,(\delta\sqrt{6n}),$$
which has indeed a monotonically increasing $n$-dependence for each $\delta\in(0,1/2)$.

Note that we recover the $\sqrt n$ slope at $\delta=0$,
$$P'_n(0)\rightarrow \sqrt{6n/\pi}\;\;\text{for}\;\;n\rightarrow\infty.$$ 
At $\delta=1$ the deviation from the exact limit $P_n(1/2)=1$ is exponentially small, $\propto\exp(-3n/2)/\sqrt n$.

The error function asymptotics is remarkably accurate already for small $n$, see the plot below for $n=3$ and $n=4$. For larger $n$ the exact and asymptotic curves are indistinguishable on the scale the figure.

[image]

---

**Bottom line.**

I would think that the finite-$n$ analytics near $\delta=0$ and $\delta=1/2$, together with the large-$n$ asymptotics for the whole interval $\delta\in(0,1/2)$, goes a long way towards a proof of the monotonic increase with $n$ of $P_n(\delta)$, although some further estimation of the error in the asymptotics is needed to complete the proof. I am surprised by the fact that the large-$n$ asymptotics is so accurate already for $n=4$.

Comment: You claim this is increasing in n?

Comment: This isn't working because you don't control the error uniformly in $n$ (if it were, it would imply that $P\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$).

Comment: Still there is a problem

Comment: So if $n \to \infty$, $P_n(\delta)$ goes to $\infty$ for any $\delta$ close to zero unless $\delta$ depends on $n$. Also can you show $C_n>0$ for all $n,\delta$?

Comment: for $n\rightarrow\infty$ the function $P_n(\delta)\rightarrow 1$ for all $\delta\in(1/2,1)$. Since this has to happen for $\delta$ arbitrarily close to $0$, the slope $P'_n(0)\rightarrow\infty$ for $n\rightarrow\infty$, and the sinc integral shows that in fact it goes to infinity as $\sqrt n$.